# JSON serialization with Spring-MVC and JPA

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a Web app using a JavaScript MVC framework (Ember.js), a Spring-MVC controller layer, and a Spring/JPA business layer. My issue is
about serializing the Java output to JSON in the Spring controller.

The controller class looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping("countries")
@ResponseBody
public Collection<Country> getAll() {
  return countryService.getAllCountries();
}

@RequestMapping("country/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public Country getById(@PathVariable Long id) {
  return countryService.getCountry(id);
}
```

The JPA entities are:

```
@Entity
class Country {

  @OneToMany
  Collection<State> states;

  //...
}

@Entity
class State {
 // ...
}
```

Method getAll is used in a screen which displays every country with a limited set of information (name, size, population). Method getById is used in a screen which displays one country with its full data set; this includes its collection of State sub-entities.

The most suggested solution in the litterature for JSON serialization is to add Jackson to the classpath and let Spring-MVC do all the magic. However letting Jackson blindly serialize every attribute is too coarse. But annotating my JPA fields with Jackson annotations such as @JsonProperty or @JsonIgnore is not attractive. First it technically couples my business layer with interface concerns. Second, it jeopardizes maintenance: any change in a JPA attribute name must be propagated up to the JavaScript code - with no help from the compiler. Third and more importantly, whether or not the entity's attribute must be serialized is not deterministic at the entity level: in the "getAll" case the States must
not be serialized, whereas in the "getById" they must be.

Can I rely on Jackson ignoring the lazy-loaded JPA relationships? For example, in a "getAll" operation, will Jackson ignore the "states" attribute of every Country?

Or should I implement manually the Java-to-JSON serialization?

Comment: Use a DTO which includes only the fields you want, copy them from the JPA object to DTO and expose the DTO to the end user. To translate from between your domain obejct and DTO you can use, for instance, [dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) or [JTransfo](http://jtransfo.org/).

Comment: Thanks Martin. If I understand your post, I should use BOTH Jackson and Dozer (or another transformer). So the @Controller function would become:

    RequestMapping("countries")
    ResponseBody
    public Collection<CountryDto> getAll() {
      Collection<Country> countries = countryService.getAllCountries();
      return transformer.toDto(countries);
    }

    RequestMapping("country/{id}")
    ResponseBody
    public CountryDto getById(@PathVariable Long id) {
      Country country = countryService.getCountry(id);
      return transformer.toDto(country);
    }

Is that what you meant?

Comment: Something like that should do the trick. Ofcourse you can also do the mapping/conversion manually but in general using something like Dozer is easier (although you have an added learning curve for another framework).